# C# - How to read from a SerialPort for an infinite amount of time

Tags: c#, serial-port, arduino

I have an arduino connected to my serialport, which generates numbers from 0 to 64 all the time.

I wanted to read these signals in c# and managed to attach them to a richtextbox.
Unfortunately at some point they stop being written in the box and i have to open the port again to append the text again to the box.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
private void btnOpenPort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        if (Arduino.IsOpen == false)
        {   
            Arduino.BaudRate = 115200;
            Arduino.PortName = cBPortWaehlen.SelectedItem.ToString();
            Arduino.Open();

        }
        while (Arduino.BytesToRead != 0) 
        {
           richTextBox1.AppendText(Arduino.ReadExisting());
        }
    }
```

I assumed the statement Arduino.BytesToRead would never turn false, as long as my arduino sends signals, but this seems not to be the case. How can I achieve that instead?

Comment: Pretty sure that it closes after it received a package with some sort of "end of package" sign, or atleast it has a timeout timer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, about any serial connection made in C# has a default event handler, called `DataReceived`. I believe that you can use it, and delete the `while` code block you have there.

Second, I think that the while block is too operation-intensive, so if you don't go with my first suggestion, try and place a `Thread.Sleep(1000)` inside your while, so it won't execute that many times. If you want to refresh the data every few milliseconds, replace `Thread.Sleep(1000)` by giving the amount of milliseconds that your prefer.

Hope this answered your question.

Later Edit:

The code you can have looks like this:

```
public void OpenArduinoConnection()
 {
     if(!arduinoBoard.IsOpen)
     {
         arduinoBoard.DataReceived += arduinoBoard_DataReceived;
         arduinoBoard.PortName = "yourportname";
         arduinoBoard.Open();
      }
      else
      {
         throw new InvalidOperationException("The Serial Port is already open!");
      }
 } 

void arduinoBoard_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   // your code here
}
```

Comment: thanks it makes a little more sense now. the signals from my arduinoboard  come with a delay of 80 ms. So I guess the best way would be to open the port exactly when the arduino sends data every 80 ms. Is there any way to synchronize them?

Comment: By the code I have given you, the port is not needed to be re-opened every 80ms. The way is to attach the DataReceived handler. This means your port will remain open throughout the whole operation, and as soon as you have incoming data, the EventHandler will trigger the `arduinoBoard_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)` method, which you can use to handle the data.

Comment: Im too new, i can't upvote yet, but i will remember you until i have enough points! Unfort. ia new problem occured now: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'richTextBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.    It seems like i can't use any windowsforms elements in that event handler.